# Compare less than today date & Autofill Issue

Tags: excel, vba

Need help with my code. I have two issues.

1. 1st issue is I try to make my code to loop if fulfill empty cell and date at column 1 less than today date
   `And .Cells(rw, 1) < Format(dt, "dd-mmm")`
   but this < today date not able to work. The macro still continue even date is greater than today date
2. 2nd issue is where i would like to autofill from column 5 to 9 from previous row. I keep encounter range error
   `Set rng = .Range(.Cells(rw - 1, 5), .Cells(rw, 9))
   Selection.AutoFill Destination:=rng, Type:=xlFillDefault`
   and
   `Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(.Cells(rw - 1, 5), .Cells(rw 1, 5)), Type:=xlFillDefault`

```vb
Sub DataGrab()
Dim rw As Long, x As Range, rng As Range
Dim extwbk As Workbook, twb As Workbook

Set twb = ThisWorkbook
Set extwbk = Workbooks.Open("D:\Users\Desktop\Report " & Format(Now, "DD-MMM-YYYY") & ".xls")
Set x = extwbk.Worksheets("Summary").Range("A4:AF100")

dt = Date

With twb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    For rw = 3 To .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        If .Cells(rw, 2) = "" And .Cells(rw, 1) < Format(dt, "dd-mmm") Then
            .Cells(rw, 2) = Application.VLookup(.Cells(rw, 1).Value2, x, 23, False)
            .Cells(rw, 3) = Application.VLookup(.Cells(rw, 1).Value2, x, 29, False)
            .Cells(rw, 4) = Application.VLookup(.Cells(rw, 1).Value2, x, 31, False)
            Set rng = .Range(.Cells(rw - 1, 5), .Cells(rw, 9))
            Selection.AutoFill Destination:=rng, Type:=xlFillDefault
            'Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(.Cells(rw - 1, 5), .Cells(rw 1, 5)), Type:=xlFillDefault
        End If
    Next rw
End With
extwbk.Close savechanges:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: Try changing of `.Cells(rw, 1) < Format(dt, "dd-mmm") ` with `.Cells(rw, 1) < CLng(dt) `. Excel doesn't care about the date format. It keeps the date as `Long`...

Comment: @DirkReichel stil encounter `Autofill method of Range class failed`

Comment: @FaneDuru `.Cells(rw, 1) < CLng(dt)` yes, this help. Thanks so much.

Comment: @LeoEY: Glad to help! I will transfer my comment to an answer... If you will tick the check box to the left side of the code, this will set it like accepted answer...

Comment: @FaneDuru thanks so much. Yup mark ticks on the comment. Left 2nd issue to troubleshoot

Comment: I must confess that I do not understand what "autofill from column 5 to 9 from previous row" means... Can you better clarify the issue?

Comment: @FaneDuru this excel is intended to copy cell value for column 2 to 4 based on the date. Then column 5 to 9 is formula calculate base on value in column 2 to 4. Example when row 4, column 1 to 4 data fill up, then I would like column 5 to 9 from row 3 autofill to  current row 4

Comment: @FaneDuru i found out the problem. The autofill occur at my external workbook instead of my active workbook. So I have to transfer `Range("E4").AutoFill Destination:=Range("E4:E" & Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row), Type:=xlFillDefault` to after `extwbk.Close savechanges:=False` external workbook close

Comment: @LeoEY: Good for you! In order to avoid such a situation, it is good to fully define your variables. Firstly, use `Option Explicit` on top of your module! This will oblige you to declare all variables. Then, never use `Range("A2")`! Use 'sh.Range("A2")`, where `sh` has previously being declared `As Workseet` and it has been set as a specific sheet: `Set sh = wb.Sheets("MySheet")`, where `wb` is the workbook (declared `As Worbook`) which has been set like: 'Set wb = Workbooks("MyWorkbook")`...

Comment: @FaneDuru Thanks for the tips. Gonna do some cleanup to my code. Thanks and appreciate for the helps!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing of `.Cells(rw, 1) < Format(dt, "dd-mmm")` with `.Cells(rw, 1) < CLng(dt)` . Excel doesn't care about the date format. It keeps and operates date as Long.

Answer (score 0):

(since I cannot comment, i'll do it through an answer)

first of all you should add `Option Explicit` at the beginning of your module. (this forces you to create variables before you give them a value)

next up, you have `.Cells(rw, 2) = " "` I assume you are trying to get the value of that cell?

if you add a `MsgBox .Cells(rw, 2)`, in your code, you see that it will not return the value of that cell. thats why you need to use `.Cells(rw, 2).Value`

Also, we don't check an empty cell with `" "` but with `if IsEmpty(.Cells(rw, 2).Value)`

this should push you in the right direction :)

Comment: .Value can be empty. I just checked it in a sheet :)

Comment: @Nemoko i try with `.Cells(rw, 2) = " "' ` it doesn't work but if `.Cells(rw, 2) = "" ` without space in between `""`, then it works. As for date i change my code from `Format(dt, "dd-mmm")` to `CLng(dt)` and it works perfectly now.